# TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION Problem while updating tfs 2010 to sp1

Tags: tfs, error-handling, database-schema

I'd applied the SP1 to an installed RTM version and when I try to access to the team server, an error indicating bad TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION occurs:

> The requested schema property TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION did not match the expected value. The server requires the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (SP1) schema but the database currently implements Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (RTM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a trick that seems to work, I just change the advanced properties of the Default collections database.
To to that:

- I connect to the SQL Server where is the tfs connected
- Change its extended property called TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION to the value that TFS expects, i.e, change the RTM that is between brachets to SP1
- Commit changes and it works

It works fine for me...